# NLTK Lexical Dispersion Plot does not show on Google Colab

Tags: python, nltk, google-colaboratory

The NLTK example code below runs just fine on my local system and shows the correct diagram (https://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html#fig-inaugural):

```
import nltk
nltk.download('book')
from nltk.book import text4
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy as np

text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy", "freedom", "duties", "America"])
```

However, it does not show the diagram when running on Google Colab. The title and axes are displayed, size and dimensions look ok but the actual dispersion plots are invisible.

Other matplotlib.pyplot diagrams do show, also all my other notebooks run on Google Colab. I have no idea why this particular diagram does not show.

System is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, browser is Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug might be related to `matplotlib backend not using Tkgg` or Colab's `pylab` library. Note that the figure is plotted using `matplotlib.pylab` (in NLTK's `dispersion.py`) and [they've seemed to discourage the use of pylab](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related). I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/397) if you want to stay updated, meanwhile you can run the code from your local compiler, save the figure and use it in Colab if the output is something you need.

You may try to display the figure in an external window instead of inline using
`%matplotlib qt`, if you get a binding error try installing `PyQt5` using `!pip install PyQt5`.

I've tried the methods above and it didn't seem to work for me, if the [issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/397) does get resolved or if you do find a solution, do post it here, please.